# Deleting from a database

Tags: php, database, sql-delete

I am trying to print out data which is stored in my database and then delete an aspect of it. See below example:
Database includes: id, room, time, date

my code is is as follows:

```
<?php


    $sql = "SELECT id, room, timers, dates, remove FROM groom WHERE person = $a";
    $result = $conn -> query ($sql);

    if($result -> num_rows >0){
        ?>

<?php
        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $row["room"] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row["timers"] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $row["dates"] ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo "Glassrooms" ?> </td>
           <td>

<?php 

echo 
"<form action='' method='post'> 
<input type='submit' name='1' value='Delete' /> 
</form>"; 

if(isset($_POST['1'])) 
{ 
    $r = $row["id"];
    $sqli ="UPDATE groom SET remove = '$a' WHERE id = $r";
    $resultt = $conn -> query ($sqli);
    echo 
"<form action='removalgr.php' method='post'> 
<input type='submit' name='usen' value='Confirm Deletion' /> 
</form>"; 

} 

?> </td> </tr>
```

What i am doing is selecting all the data from a database groom where it relates to the person logged in. It prints it out fine in the following format which is perfect:

```
Room   Time   Date    Area  DeleteBooking
 1       4    2/3/17   BB     Delete
```

And the where it says delete is a button which allows for the booking to be deleted. However my problem is this:

when there is more than one booking, they all delete because below they are being called the same thing. see here:

```
<input type='submit' name='useb' value='Delete' />
```

Is it possible to call the above name something different everytime, or alternatively call it the id of the booking?

Hopefully this makes sense and any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: Nooo... don't format SQL queries yourself...

Comment: You have **2** forms. The button is in the second. Therefore that is all that is in that form so you never pass any real data

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input with the ID of the item to be deleted.

```
echo 
    "<form action='' method='post'> 
     <input type='hidden' name='id' value='{$row['id']}'>
    <input type='submit' name='1' value='Delete' /> 
    </form>";
```